# Trigger GA pageview depending on URL string

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I have a form that will return values in its URL, including whether the form is valid or not
/contact2.php?result=contact-error-captcha&name=John
/contact2.php?result=contact-ok&name=John

I am trying to trigger a Google Analytics Pageview depending on this value, but I can't manage to associate PHP and JS properly.

Here is my last attempt, but it seems to not execute. 
Any help appreciated :)

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function error-captcha() {
         alert("Hello! This works");
         ga('send', 'pageview', '/pages/contact-error-captcha');
     } 
     function contact-ok() {
         ga('send', 'pageview', '/pages/contact-ok');
     } 
     <?php if( $_GET['result'] == 'contact-error-captcha') : echo "error-captcha();"; endif; ?>
     <?php if( $_GET['result'] == 'contact-ok') :  echo "contact-ok();"; endif; ?>
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks B. Desai [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135231/trigger-javascript-function-depending-on-php-condition)
The issue is with "-" in javascript functions, replacing them with "_" solves the issue ex: function error_captcha()